# AMCAR-4 red dot disappeared

Tags: payday-the-heist

Why can't I toggle these starred items? I have the accuracy IV unlocked for the [AMCAR-4](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/AMCAR-4) and had it for one game. Now it's back to iron sights, and I can't toggle it back. It seems pressing X in the upgrades tree makes no diffrence.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for testing this is to go into a single player game on any map, and try from the upgrades menu there if you haven't already.

Visual changes occur immediately from in here, so if you're holding your AMCAR when you do so, the carryhandle sight should swap out while the game is paused, allowing you to see the changes on the spot.

If this doesn't work, get back to me and I'll look into it further for you.